# Do the Stack and Heap both exist within your systems RAM?

Tags: java, windows, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

The question is pretty much the same as the title, do the Stack and Heap exist within the RAM at all times? Assuming Windows is the OS of the machine in question.

Also, if the answer to the above question is yes, is it possible to tell the JVM to create a specific applications Stack and Heap in a different location, such as an external micro SD card? Or to just set the default Stack/Heap creation location to some location other than RAM?

Comment: The Stack and the Heap are data structures.  Whether they exist in memory or not depends on whether your operating system or programming language creates and maintains those structures.

Comment: Right, I will edit the question to assume Windows. The programming language I am referring to specifically is Java, and the question is tageed with the Java tag.

Comment: Is there any reason behind your question apart from idle curiosity? Given that a program's Heap could be made to reside on an external micro SD card, what would you do with that card, and when? Stop the program, pull the card and investigate it??

Comment: Well I was wondering if it would be a viable option for a system with a very limited amount of RAM, if I still wanted to run a prgram in Java, without using native code. I realize now it's not lol.

Comment: OK, that's what I suspected. But the GBytes are cheap...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, they might not be in RAM at **all** times. The stack and heap are just data structures allocated in RAM.  When your program is actually using the CPU, they both will exist (at least partially) in RAM.  However, it is possible that the OS will swap out the pages that the stack and heap are on when the program is not running.  Then part of (or all) of the stack and heap could be written to disk.

I would guess that you would not be able to tell the JVM to allocate those data structures any place else.  I cannot picture a scenario where you would want to; it would be horrifically slow.  I am sure they are allocated with malloc() or a system call and it is unlikely the JVM would have any conditional code for that type of allocation.

Comment: One thing you _may_ be able to do is alter the location of the JVM's heap and stack. But that would be native code, and it would require some understanding of the underlying operating system. It wouldn't be portable. It also probably wouldn't map to the heap + stack of the application running within the JVM.

Comment: So the Heap/Stack of an application running within the JVM *are not* stored within the same Heap and Stack of the JVM? My apps Stack/Heap isn't a subset of my JVM's Stack/Heap? Just want to clear that up, sorry if it's a noob question.

Comment: Also I really appreciate your descriptive answer, and @Parthian Shot's accompanying comment.

Comment: `Heap/Stack of an application running within the JVM are not stored within the same Heap and Stack of the JVM` No- sorry I wasn't clear. There are two different heap+stack combos, one nested within the other. One is the native JVM heap+stack, which is mapped into memory by the operating system. The other is the _virtual_ heap+stack which the JVM creates within its own memory. So, the O/S allocates memory for the JVM process, and then the JVM allocates memory for the internal Java application to use for its operations.

Comment: @AdamJ If I understood your original question correctly, you want the internal Java heap+stack to be put somewhere, and as far as I know, that isn't something you can specify without modifying the source code of the JVM itself (not recommended). However, there _may_ be a way to map the memory of the running JVM process onto files or devices other than main memory. If I were you, I'd look into that. Unless it's really important that you separate the internal heap and stack across different devices, in which case I wouldn't want to be you- you'd have to rewrite your Java to make that happen.

Comment: @AdamJ Basically, the two easiest ways I can see to make what you'd want to happen happen would be (1) Spend a couple hours seeing if you can (easily) remap process memory to some file or device (in a similar way to the way the OS uses a swap file), and if that doesn't pan out in a reasonable period of time (2) start rewriting the Java program from the ground up to act like a database, and keep as much state as possible in regular files.